# webservices : Are xs:string and xsd:string are same ??

Tags: web-services, cxf

We have developed Webservices using Apache CXF , and they are working fine .

This is some part of our generated wsdl file (http://localhost:8080/MyWeb/tata/soap?wsdl).

```
   <xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="strikePrice" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="symbol" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>

<soap:body use="literal"/>
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```

We have developed Webservices using Apache CXF , and they are working fine .

While reading webservice performance tuning  tutorials ,  i read always use document literal for interoperabilty .

My question is , is my WSDL is document /literal ??

Because most of the tutorials in internet , represent xsd:String in place of (xs:String) for representing document/literal approach ??

Are xs:String  and xsd:String  are same ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xs:string and xsd:string are the same, provided that the "xs" and "xsd" prefixes are both bound to the namespace URI "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema".